# Start a fire with key fob battery?

Tags: survival, fire-starting, improvised-gear

We know that you [can start a fire with a battery.](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/starting-a-fire-with-a-battery-what-are-the-fundamental-guidelines-for-safety) the better prepared you are the easier it is going to be.

I am not prepared and all I have in my pockets is my car keys, which includes a keyless entry fob that has a '3v Lithium Coin Cell Battery'  is it possible to start a fire with this battery?  All I have is the metal key ring, finger nail clippers, and a couple of other keys on the ring.

I don't have a tiny screwdriver to get the battery out, so I am going to have to use a rock to break the key fob.  I suspect that [banging two rocks together would be a more effective fire starter,](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/is-there-a-way-to-light-a-fire-in-the-wild-using-rocks) but I might be wrong.

Can I start a fire with  my key fob battery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With just the right equipment in a laboratory setting, you can use the energy in a key fob battery to cause a spark.  You can then use that to start a fire under the right conditions.

**However**, that's not going to happen in any realistic back country conditions.  The voltage and current capability of a key fob battery are just too low.

The reason you can sometimes use a car battery for starting a fire is because a car battery can deliver a massive amount of current.  When shorting the battery with a small wire, the contact point gets so hot that some of the metal is vaporized, causing a spark.  Sometimes small amounts of molten metal are also shed off.  A key fob battery just doesn't have the oomph to do that.

In addition, it's not easy to start a fire with just a electric spark unless you have ignitable vapor.  A few drops of stove fuel on tinder, then letting that vaporize for a few seconds can work, but trying to light solid tinder directly is very difficult.  The reason this is sometimes successful with a car battery is due to the molten metal resulting from the high current, not the spark itself.  With a car battery, you can even get small wire to glow, and then melt.  A key fob battery isn't capable of that.

Comment: Steel wool is the easiest way to use a battery to start a fire. Even a PP3 (with a fairly high internal resistance) will get very dry tinder (or liquid fuel) going using steel wool. Now I want to experiment!

Comment: @Chris: Yes, what you really want is very thin wire.  Steel wool is a handy way to get such wire.  Steel also has the advantage of oxidizing when heated enough.  In this case, steel wool isn't available.  Although I haven't tried it, I expect a key fob battery to be too week to get steel wool hot enough to start a fire.  You need something with decent current capability, like a flashlight battery.

Comment: Steel's high resistivity compared to electrical wire is also a help. Brass (from the keys) is also a poor conductor but I don't think there's any way to make a filament out of it with the constraints in the question

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I'm really curious to hear what you think is wrong.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219847/testing-chinese-cr2032-li-ion-battery-capacity Some notes on keyfob batteries

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234901/lithium-coin-cell-cr2032-battery-specifications More keyfob battery notes.  New battery momentary 0.1amp peak @ 3V so 0.3W and that’s best-case.  So you’d better have made some good tinder (with your Survival Nailclipper)

Comment: For reference a candle is 60-80 watts (so says the internet) so starting a fire with 0.3 watts is going to be a challenge

Comment: @mmcc: There is a very big difference in short circuit current and internal resistance between a AAA battery and a coin cell, even a large one like a CR2032.  You're just not going to get "steel wool" hot enough to start a fire with just a small coin cell.  I'm a electrical engineer, and I could design a circuit that would make a spark powered from only a coin cell.  However, the required parts aren't available in the wilderness.  Making a spark and heating wire to burning temperature are also two different things.

Comment: @OlinLathrop just to completely beat this dead horse I tried this out (shorted a CR2016 with single strand of fine steel wool) and couldn’t make it singe paper.  So your EE instincts/back of envelope math is correct.  Deleting other speculative comments.

Answer (score 4):

A bit more than a comment on Olin's answer:

I've done an experiment, and no, you can't.

I took:

- a brand new CR2025
- some steel wool to make it easier; this is a nice firelighting filament with bigger batteries
- a tissue

I shorted the cell using the steel wool, held in a pad of tissue to provide tinder and keep the heat in.  It got fairly warm for a couple of minutes, even through the tissue, but when it cooled and I opened the tissue it wasn't even blackened.  If I couldn't get close with the contents of a house and garage at my disposal, you're not going to be able to do it in the field.

Comment: Agreed.  I tried too (CR2016 and a single strand of fine steel wool) and got nothing.